# Generating Jenkins pipeline without using DSL in a shared library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to write a shared library to generate a full pipeline, but I'm struggling to mix my logic with the pipeline DSL, so I'd love to just bypass the DSL altogether and "assemble" the pipeline by hand.

For example, instead of

```
def call() {
    node {
        stage("Hello world") {
            echo "Hello world"
        }
    }
}
```

I'd love to do something like

```
def call() {
    s = new Stage("Hello world")
    s.addStep({echo "Hello world"}) // or maybe s.addStep(new EchoStep("Hello world"))

    n = new Node()
    n.addStage(s)

    return n
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? Failing that, are there any good examples for how to mix "plugin-time logic" (decide what stages to create and what steps they should have) with "runtime logic" (do something if a file exists, do something else if a test fails, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with groovy closure. You can find a bunch of examples in google, like https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/

The basic concept is that closure is runable and can be passed as a parameter. You can do something like

```
def helloWorld() {
  return {
    stage("Hello world") {
        echo "Hello world"
    }
  }
}

def runInNode(body){
   node {
      body()
   }
}

def call(){
  runInNode(helloWorld)
}
```